# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting with sql execute in Python

Tags: python, pymysql

The code below

```
varlist =[]
for key, value in json_obj.iteritems():
    print key, value
    varlist = varlist + ["string"]
print varlist


params = ['?' for item in varlist]
query_string    = 'INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (%s);' % ','.join(params)
print query_string
cursor.execute(query_string, varlist)
```

produces the following

```
['string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string']  
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./vpn.py", line 26, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query_string, varlist)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 164, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 143, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I have also tried with

```
cursor.execute(query_string, (varlist,))
```

but it doesn't work either.Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

From example in [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html):

```
insert_stmt = (
  "INSERT INTO employees (emp_no, first_name, last_name, hire_date) "
  "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
)
data = (2, 'Jane', 'Doe', datetime.date(2012, 3, 23))
cursor.execute(insert_stmt, data)
```

Note `%s` in query line. That's how `cursor.execute` knows where to put values. In your case query is already filled and that results in error.